# How can I run Flex/BlazeDS without dropping a JSessionId cookie?

Tags: apache-flex, cookies, blazeds, remoteobject

The question says it. Does anybody know the answer to this? We're running into problems when 3rd-party cookies are disabled.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What is the actual description of "Dropping"?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com: If 3rd-party cookies are disabled, calls to a RemoteObject fail with the `FaultEvent.fault.faultCode` "Server.Processing.DuplicateSessionDetected". This appears to be because the RemoteObject method call initializing the service drops the JSessionId cookie.

Comment: So, then by "drops" do you mean that the cookie is not passed as part of the RemoteObject call?

Comment: @Robusto, are you sure it's not a server side issue?  Because a 'session' is not the same as a 'cookie'.  Session is unique between your BlazeDS and Flex.

Comment: @J_A_X: Apparently this happens from the SWF. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6764413/271917, which hasn't been answered either.

Comment: @Robusto, that link is this question... And even if it appears in the SWF, did you check the server logs?  One cannot operate without the other and this error came from the server, hence the `Server.Processing.DuplicateSessionDetected`.  I don't think you've debugged enough on both the front end and the server end.

Comment: @J_A_X: The front end has been debugged. I make the initialization call to the service and get a FaultEvent response. There is no code between the two that can be debugged. So it seems like the server side is what needs to be debugged, no?

Comment: It helps to have the server side debugged, yes.  I'm fairly positive it's a server issue with the session management.  It would also be helpful to add the code that tries to call the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your browser does not accept cookies the application server should maintain the session using a jsessionid passed in the url. BlazeDS will be aware about that and it will also add the jsessionid to the AMF messages (and on the client it will be read and added to the other requests).

If that's the case you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614298/duplicate-flex-sessions-with-cross-domain-requests/6621912#6621912) post..there are some links to a couple of articles. If you receive the error even after reading the articles (and applying the suggestions) it would be good to create a running test case (and I can take a look on it).

Comment: Good answer - but the link to the post appears to be missing?

Comment: My mistake, I'm growing older :) I've added the link.